# Using the fullText field with google drive api

Tags: php, google-api-php-client

I am running into a issue with the google drive API.
I downloaded the library with composer and it installed correctly and seems to work. When i try to search my drive on file title or mimtypes it works great but when i want to use the fullText field it fails with the folowing error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message 'Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?q=fullText%3D%27Werken+met+procestaken+op+een+klant+project%27: (400) Invalid query'
```

**My code**

```
function searchFile($query,$service){
    $pageToken = null;
    do {
        $response = $service->files->listFiles(array(
            'q' => "fullText='".$query."'",
        ));
        foreach ($response->items as $file) {
            printf("Bestand gevonden: %s (%s)\n", $file->title, $file->id);
        }
    } while ($pageToken != null);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing it wrong. Here is how it is suposed to work. Maybe it can help some one in the future.

```
function searchFile($query,$service){
    $pageToken = null;
    do {
        $response = $service->files->listFiles(array(
          'corpus' => 'DEFAULT',
          'q' => "fullText contains '".$query."'",
         ));

    foreach ($response->items as $file) {
        printf("Bestand gevonden: %s (%s)\n", $file->title, $file->id);
    }
  } while ($pageToken != null);
}
```